# Accessing linkedin api without repetitive sign in?

Tags: api, linkedin-api, sign

I am new to linkedin api. I have a doubt regarding the api.

I am integrating the api in my application, so different user have to register in the linkedin to get the data using that api? Can it be pre registered and the user can get the data whatever he wants.

Suppose user wants to search about company. He will type the company name and will get the names of the company related to search. He should not log in in linked in before searching.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [JavaScript API](http://developer.linkedin.com/javascript), then yes, you may need to have the user log in each time as the JavaScript API's authorization is cleared every time the user closes their browser.

If you are using the [REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest), you can store the user's OAuth token and use that to make the calls on behalf of the user, saving them having to sign-in each time.

Comment: can u give me an example of it... i have no idea about REST API so any example would be beneficial for me.

Comment: You can see a live demo of the REST API in action [here](http://www.simplelinkedin.com/demo/) - the source code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/)